# React Native + firebase storage : Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, storage

I'm coding an application with react native + expo + firebase.

I'm trying to code a function to load image to firebase storage.

I get an error when I use uploadBytes function from firebase stroage SDK. I get this error : Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.

My variable storage is initailized in other file with getStorage(app).

My code :

console.log('Load Image!')

```
  console.log('blob !')
  
  const storageRef = ref(storage, '/profil');

  console.log('upload !')

  // 'file' comes from the Blob or File API

  const bytes = new Uint8Array([0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21]);
  uploadBytes(storageRef, bytes,'')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Uploaded an array!');
  })
```

Do you have any ideas ?

I'm trying to read file with function listAll.

I get the same error

Comment: Do you try to use the `includes` property somewhere in your code?

Comment: No I don't try to use includes property. I suppose that the property includes is used in firebase SDK. What do you think ?

Comment: After two months of suffering I solved my issue ! :D. The module AppCheck was activate for storage :'(. It's a very simple thing :'(